# How can I find partial pivoting matrix $P$ from $PA=LU$ decomposition if we know $A,L,U$?

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra, lu-decomposition

Assume that we have this equation

$$PA=LU$$

Where $A \in \Re^{mxn}$, $L \in \Re^{mxn}$ is a lower triangular matrix and $U \in \Re^{nxn}$ is an upper triangular matrix. $P \in \Re^{mxm}$ is the partial pivoting matrix.

In this case, $A,U,L$ are known. How can I find $P$?

Can I take

$$P = LUA^{\dagger}$$

?

Comment: Every algorithm for computing LU decomposition with partial pivoting gives you also $P$ in some way. Why would you do this?

Comment: Because I using Lapack subroutine dgetrf_ , and the P-matrix is not a matrix, it's more like a vector that describe how the P-matrix should be. That's not a problem. The real problem is that the P-vector is one element to short. I think it's a bug inside dgetrf_. Here is an example: https://github.com/DanielMartensson/EmbeddedLapack/blob/master/EmbeddedLapack/src/LinearAlgebra/lu.c

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel If you want to contribute with some C-code for solving the pivot matrix, it would be very helpfull for this free library.

Comment: What do you mean by one element too short?

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel It seems that Lapack solve $A=PLU$ and MATLAB solve $PA=LU$. I have now made so Lapack solve $PA=LU$ :) Just look at the lu.c file from https://github.com/DanielMartensson/EmbeddedLapack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is correct.

Your problem seems to be that LAPACK doesn't return the pivoting matrix, but a permutation vector. This thread might help: http://icl.cs.utk.edu/lapack-forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=1747

Comment: Hi! I have solve my problem now. Have a look at lu.c file from EmbededLapack. https://github.com/DanielMartensson/EmbeddedLapack